# Uncaught Syntax errors

Tags: javascript

I am working on a quiz app for class and I keep getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" in the console. I have tried looking up YouTube videos for solutions and have even tried fixing the code through similar posts on this site. I am at a loss and can't figure out what is wrong.

```js
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const saveScoreBtn = document.querySelector('#saveScoreBtn');
const finalScore = document.querySelector('#finalScore');
const mostRecentScore = localStorage.getItem('mostRecentScore');

const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('highScores')) || [];

const MAX_HIGH_SCORES = 5;

finalScore.innerText = mostRecentScore;

username.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    saveScoreBtn.disabled = !username.value;
});

saveHighScore = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const score = {
        score: mostRecentScore,
        name: username.value
    };

    highScores.push(score);

    highScores.sort((a,b) =>{
        return b.score - a.score;
    })
    

    highScores.splice(5);

    localStorage.setItem('highscores', JSON.stringify(highScores));

    window.location.assign('../high-scores/highscores.html')
};
```

Comment: You should try `console.log(localStorage.getItem('highScores'))`.  It's probably invalid JSON.  You can manually clear it with `localStorage.clear()` once.

Comment: You can also use your browser dev tools _Application_ tab to inspect the contents of _Local Storage_. My guess... at some stage you wrote an object to `localStorage` without _stringifying_ it so it got saved as `[object Object]`

Answer (score -1):

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

That means this is not json formated code. Check your json again.